# How to load huge data in datatables with jquery ajax from node js as back-end?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I am trying to load around 10,000 records(rows) into DataTable with jquery ajax. So, what are all the syntax i need to write inside datatable? What is the format that should be returned so as to implement the pagination with ajax in datatable ?

i am now adding rows into datatable via the syntax `table.row.add([<parameter1>,<parameter2>...]);` via for() loop, so when huge data is getting loaded, the table data appears only after all the rows are getting added, until that whole page gets hanged since its loading huge number of rows. The Data is loaded from MySql stored procedures.

Datatable:

```
var listProductsTable = $(".listProductsTable").DataTable({
    "pagingType": "full",
    "columnDefs":[
        {
            "targets":9,
            "render": function() {
                return '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" style="font-size:30px;" id="edit_product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editProductModal"></i>';
            }
        },
        {
            "targets":10,
             "render": function(data,type,row) {
                //console.log(data,type,row);
                return '<input type="checkbox" id="disable_product" val="" class="js-switch">';
             }
        },
        { "width": "10%", "targets": "_all"  },
        {
             "orderable": false,
             "targets": 0,
        }
    ],
    "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
    "dom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"p><"clear">',
    "createdRow": function (row, data, index) {
        var switchElem = Array.prototype.slice.call($(row).find('.js-switch'));
        switchElem.forEach(function (html) {
            var switchery = new Switchery(html, { color: '#66FE43', secondaryColor: '#dee2e6' });
        });
    }
});

    /* numbering */
    listProductsTable.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
        listProductsTable.column(0, {/*search:'applied',*/ order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i+1;
        });
    }).draw();
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: serverurl + "getdata",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    cache: false,
    data:JSON.stringify(productsData),
    success:function(productsdata)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < productsdata.Response.length; i++) {
            listProductsTable.row.add([id,code,category,....]).draw(false);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Have you tryed datatables.net? I prefer to use their server-side solution, with the Scroller extension, if the tablerows count is over ~2000. https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

Comment: 1 stop and think about what you're doing.  Browsers simply aren't designed to handle this much data.  2 consider how you load the data - one row at a time seems hugely wasteful.  3 you want "pagination with ajax" yet you've already loaded all the data - that's contradictory.  The datatables documentation has a lot of info on how to correctly setup ajax paging.

Comment: With that solution, you will only have to load a couple of hundres at the time. It's very fast, and you will still have the scrollbar so you doesn't have to use paging.

Comment: I have tried the server side processing and it works perfectly, and pagination is done same as the official documentation of DataTable. @radbyx, I also tried your solution, but when huge data is getting "appended" using the row.add([...]) function, it will be slow. There was a npm package named "nodetable" ,which does this trick in the back-end. Thanks for quick replies.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by appending alot, because the solution i describe you clear you table and the response only contains few hundres rows.

Comment: @radbyx I also found solution for adding rows by 1. first getting the data from node and then storing the data in an array of objects, 2. put the datatable definition inside a function which accepts an argument of an array, 3. define "data" attribute with name of the array, 4. define "columns" attribute pertaining to the names in the array of objects .so whenever the API is called via ajax data is passed to function and passed onto datatable. it loads instantly.